# How do do Bootstrap 3 scrollspy on subnav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I can get the scrollspy to work on the first layer of nav, but I also have subnavs in each link, just like the one on bootstrap's page: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix, but I've tried for a while and just couldn't get the subnav to work...

Does anyone know the minimum structure to get the scrollspy to work on a two layer nav menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work the same way. Make sure that your hrefs have the correct id's

Here's an example...
http://www.bootply.com/533U4Zo7Uq

Comment: But your example does not track the sub nav, it only shows the sub nav but not on each specific sub nav... mine works like that already

Comment: It works when there are corresponding sections with `id`s.. http://www.bootply.com/render/NRCMUnJKYe